# MutableLiveData setValue does not execute next code

Tags: kotlin, mutablelivedata

I have

```
var test : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>("test")
...
somewhere callback fun from library {
    println("test 1")
    test.value = "123"
    println("test 2")
}
```

However only `test 1` is printed in the log. Does anyone know this issue and how to solve this? I have checked that the callback runs on main thread though.

Note:

Issues only happens on that callback, it is fine if I `.value` in other code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by I need to explicitly assign the value inside main thread:

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(Runnable {
    test.value = "123"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
test.postValue("123")
```

It would help

Comment: Could you please explain why exactly this helps. Does setValue block when executed on a non-main thread?

Comment: No this is not what I want because I need to use setValue, so the value is passed back to the observer.

Comment: @EvgenyBovykin yes, it is the difference between setValue() and postValue()

Comment: @Rendy postValue() could do the same thing as setValue() beside the main thread where the setValue() couldn't be called